# Can't Select in Laravel using Eloquent and SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, laravel

Greatings,
I'm very new in laravel. Today I make a project with Laravel and SQL Server for the database.
I can connect to that DB, and I can make the default migration using user migration. but when I select the table user and return it into json the result is blank.
That's my select

```
    {
        //
        $dataUser = User::all();
        return response()->json($dataUser);
    }
```

and the result only [] on browser, I use Postman too, but the result was same. I have 2 record on DB.

and then wan't to do with different table, I'm use existing table, the table name is Purchases, the table have around 100 record. and that's my model for the table

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchases extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Purchases';
    protected $primaryKey = 'PurchaseID';
    protected $guarded = ['PurchaseID'];
    const CREATED_AT = 'CreatedTime';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'LastModifiedTime';
}
?>
```

I use the same code in the purchaseController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Purchases;

public function index()
    {
        //
        $dataPurchase = Purchases::all();
        return response()->json($dataPurchase);
    }
```

but when I load the browser that return error like this

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'purchases'. (SQL: select * from [purchases])
```

in my SSMS, my table is [dbo].[purchases] and the migration is [dbo].[users]

Please help me to resolve that.
Thankyou

**EDIT**: I think I have a problem on my connection, because I only register the php PDO driver on apache, and change the laravel config. I can using migration, but when I use faker, the data that's showing on tinker not save on DB users

Comment: your table name is `Purchases` or `purchases` (note the uppercase)?

Comment: In ssms i see that P upercase [dbo].[Purchases]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code perfectly worked in my project.
check your database connection in env or databse.php

Comment: Thankyou sir, may I know your database (MySQL or SQL Server)?, because I use SQL Server and when I dd($MySelected) that return []

Comment: i am also using SQL Server

Comment: sory @Ankita, can you tell me how to config the sql server? because I only register the pdo driver, and change the laravel config on env and app.config, do I need other tools maybe. because i try using faker, and no data store on db users

Comment: In .env
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=finaldb
DB_USERNAME= root
DB_PASSWORD= 

and database.php
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv')

Comment: Thankyou Ankita, I forgot declare the db on model, because i using 2 DB, after I remove the 2nd connection, that's work